# mySQL PreparedStatement vs. Statement in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

In my program I have to update the data in an database. For this I created a UPDATE statement. Only the changed textfields should be updatet. Here the important part of my program:

```
String update = "UPDATE members set " + TFArray[i].getUserData().toString() +" = \"" + TFArray[i].getText() +"\" WHERE MemberNr = " + m.getMemberNr() + ";";
System.out.println(update);
statement = DBConnection.connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(update);
DBConnection.connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
DBConnection.connection.commit();
DBConnection.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

This works perfectly. But for a general UPDATE statement I wanted to use a prepared statement like that one:

```
String update = "UPDATE members SET ? = \" ? \" WHERE MEMBERNR = ?;";
ps = DBConnection.connection.prepareStatement(update);
ps.setString(1, TFArray[i].getUserData().toString()); 
ps.setString(2, TFArray[i].getText()); 
ps.setString(3, m.getMemberNr()); 
ps.addBatch(); 
DBConnection.connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
ps.executeBatch(); 
DBConnection.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

With this string I get an exception which says that the parameter is out of range (3 > 2).

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statement parameters only work for query values not column names. String concatenation should be avoided due to the risk of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
String update = "UPDATE members SET FIELD = ? WHERE MEMBERNR = ?";
```

Comment: oh, ok. Thank you for this. I've nevert thought about SQL Injections...

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind column name. So the code should look like this (be careful about sql injection!):

```
  String update = "UPDATE members SET " + TFArray[i].getUserData().toString() + " = ? WHERE MEMBERNR = ?";
  ps = DBConnection.connection.prepareStatement(update);
  ps.setString(1,TFArray[i].getText()); 
  ps.setString(2,m.getMemberNr()); 
  ps.addBatch(); 
  DBConnection.connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
  ps.executeBatch(); 
  DBConnection.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think i'll use my normal statement. As Reimeus said, I should avoid the risk of SQL injection. Another reason is, that my String is defined outside the FOR-loop. So I it won't work with index "i".